# Excel file Import to Sql Server, Sql Server Table have indexes and Excel file have Names

Tags: sql-server

I want to import Excel File to SQL Server, but my problem is the Table which I created in SQL for excel file save indexes and Foreign Keys.

Like SQLTable have `ID`, `StudentName`, `ClassID`, `SectionID`, etc...but my Excel file have not `Class ID` it has `Class name` in it. Similarly Section Name instead of `SectionID`.

How I will import the file to database.

Thank you

Comment: If you are using the 32-bit or 64-bit SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, on the Select Source Tables and Views screen there is a button to Edit Mappings. Once you click this and get into the Column Mappings dialog, you can choose the destination field (aka column) for each of your import fields (or choose to ignore a field).

Comment: @Jeeped .. As i say in question the table i created in SQL save the index's like Class one has index no 3. so i save 3 in `classID` field of SQL Table, while my excel file cell have class one not index. how i will save indexes??? with mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to map the names to IDs before you can load the Excel data into the table. I can think of three ways to do it:

a) Import the Excel data into a new table, and then write some SQL to join to the relevant tables to get the IDs, and then do the insert into the target table.

b) Query your database directly from Excel to get the IDs that you need, and then use the SQL import wizard to import the data into the target table.

c) Write an SSIS package to read the Excel data, query the database for the additional IDs, and insert into your target table.